# Javascript declaration issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, declaration

//PROBLEM SOLVED//
It turned out that the JQuery Ajax call couldn't reach the URL in certain browsers.

Thanks anyway guys, for your quick responses, definitly helped to work it out.

Sorry for the non-specific title, I don't even think what should be the problem.

There is a JQuery plugin (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) which counts down from a specific date or time.

The end time from which the counter should start can be defined in 2 ways: either setting a date either setting the number of seconds left.

My project needs the second one and based on the documentation this option has to be declared like:

```
$('#digital_hour').countdown({until: +300});
```

Notice the "+" sign before the number.

It works nice on any OS and device, UNTIL I replace the number 300 with a variable that stores the seconds left until the end of the day on the server. So this version:

```
$('#digital_hour').countdown({until: +seconds_left_on_server});
```

works on specific browsers, but on others don't. Strangly enought it works under my Vista/Mozilla20.0 combo, but it doesn't on my Vista/IE6, nor on my friends Ubuntu/Mozilla combo.

I'm not a huge javascript admirer, nor an expert on the subject, but I feel that there is something around the "+" sign.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: The ones that handle it correctly start counting down like 12:36:13 (H:M:S), but the other ones show a weird number at the HOUR mark and count down from there. This weird number at the hour mark is always 9 digits long instead of two. And of course nor the minutes, nor the seconds aren't correct.

Comment: Yes, I tried the brackets in a few way, but none of them worked.

Comment: I even tried to concatenate the + sign with the variable before declaring it in the "until" section, but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
$('#digital_hour').countdown({until: new Date(+(new Date()) + 1000 * seconds_left_on_server)});
```

Comment: This solution returns NaN for all(hours, minutes, seconds) on IE6. Still works in Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something simple like `var seconds_left = 300` and then `$('#digital_hour').countdown({until: +seconds_left});` and see what happens?

It sounds like your variable is not storing what it should. The "+" shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes. This way it works. I made a little workarond. I writed out the variable returned by the php and in Mozilla I see a number: 24624, but in IE6 I see this: Sat May 18 17:09:40 UTC+0300 2013

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, definitly helped me to work out that the problem was caused by the URL of the Ajax call. For some reasons at times it doesn't reach its location.